# Is there any way to serve binary file input(stream?) directly to multer middleware(for unit test purpose)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, multipartform-data, supertest

I'm trying to write test codes on multer and my service.

As multer is an express's middleware, multer is intended to process the request from client and automatically handle the file and put it in `req.file`.

But I wonder if there is any way without making real HTTP request, to pass binary file or stream to multer middleware so that I can check whether the file is saved in local disk properly or the file's size is put afterward in `req.file`.

My code as middleware module of multer is below, just for reference:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';

const multerMiddleware = (dest: string) => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
      destination: dest,
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const { videoId } = req.body;
        const filename = `${videoId}-${file.originalname}`;
        cb(null, filename);
      }
    })
  });

  upload.single('file')(req, res, next);
}

export default multerMiddleware;
```

Or, is it the best way to do just make a test-purpose route in Express app and test with it? Like below:

```
app.post('/testMulter', multerMiddleware('temp/'), (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200);
  res.json(req.file);
  // ...
});

// in test codes
import request from 'supertest'
import App from '../app.ts'

it('multer middleware download files well', async (done) => {
  const app = new App.app;

  const response = await request(app)
    .post('/testMulter')
    .attach('file', './test.mp4');
  expect(response.file.filename).toBe('test.mp4');
})
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do an integrational test but without HTTP stuff.
According to the provided code, only `req.body` is used. In terms of the unit testing, it is simple to mock such `Request`.
But we do not "know" how `multer` uses `Request` and `Response`. So if you still want to do an integrational test, you approach is good enough.
Overwise it is better to pass `{ body: { videoId: fakeId } }` instead of `Request` and mock `multer`, `multer.diskStorage`, and `and` multer.single`.